# Missing Basic Javadoc in Eclipse for Java 11

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I recently switched from java 8 to java 11 in eclipse, by installing the newer jdk and switching the jre in eclipse. The first thing i noticed, that was not working properly, was the javadoc, which read : "Note: This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc."

I then looked up other users with similar problems, but they were all using different versions of java, and the link in my javadoc configuration doesn't work.

(the validate button when selecting the javadoc url also returns
"Location might be invalid."
for the URL
"https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/").

I suspect that I still have an the old java 8 javadoc installed, which is now looking in the wrong place, but i couldn't find another java 11 javadoc link anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a workaround, download the offline documentation from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-doc-downloads.html

In your Eclipse project, open "JRE System Library", right-click "java.base", choose "Properties" from context menu.

In the dialog, check the radio button "Javadoc in archive". For the field "Archive path", browse to your downloaded zip. For the field "Path within archive", browse to "docs/api/java.base". Then, "Apply and Close".

Comment: "docs/api/java.base" does not indicate a valid path. I have STS 3 installed:Version: 3.9.12.RELEASE
Build Id: 202003180826
Platform: Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13.0)  , The correct path is "docs/api" which when validated works but i still cannot get the Javadoc to work when i press F2 on Java Class like "String".  It says that element has no attached source and Javadoc could not be found.  Any Pointers ?

Comment: When clicking the "Validate"-button a message "Location might be invalid" is displayed. However, for me it is working.

Comment: ... at least for classes in module "java.base" (`String`, `Math`, ...). This is of course only a workaround. Swing classes are in "java.desktop" instead of "java.base". If you configure that to work, "java.base" classes are not longer working. I could also not find a way to configure documentation a level up as you tried. Seems to be a bug. Eclipse Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0). Build id: 20191212-1212

Comment: Yes, i tried the same, java.base works for me too. Is there a place to report this issue , eclipse git forum or some other website.